# Google slides php, manage share settings

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-slides-api

I've initialized the Google Slides PHP API and already created a presentation successfully.
Now my question is: How do change the share settings of the created presentation?

Comment: You can share it using [Permissions in Driver API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions).

Comment: welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question and show us what you have tried and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The share settings of any file that exists in Drive can be managed via [Permissions resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions)  from Drive API. You can [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create), [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update) or [delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/delete) a permission by making the corresponding call to the API.

For example, if you want to share your file with someone, or make it public, you just have to call `Permissions.create` and provide the `id` of the file in your request, as well as the following properties in [the request body](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create#request-body):

- `type`: you can specify if you want to share the file with a single user, with all users in your domain, make it public or what have you.
- `role`: you can specify if the user that is granted access to the file can edit it, just view it, or what have you.

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally got my project to work, but with some workarounds.

Comment: @TheInfectedWolf you're welcome. If this answer was useful to you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), since it can be useful to others, and StackOverflow relies on this to share knowledge to other users.